# Invalid Token Error Asing AWS logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have been battling this for hours and it's driving me nuts. I installed log agent and set it up correctly.

I can access the instance via this command. `eb ssh`

However, when I run the command `sudo service awslogs restart` , I get weird errors like

```
 2017-06-12 16:31:41,899 - cwlogs.push.publisher - WARNING - 31909 -   
 Thread-7 - Caught exception: An error occurred 
 (UnrecognizedClientException) when calling the PutLogEvents operation: 
 The security token included in the request is invalid.

 2017-06-12 16:31:41,899 - cwlogs.threads - ERROR - 31909 - Thread-7 - 
 Exception caught in <EventBatchPublisher(Thread-7, started daemon 
 140242458298112)>

 Traceback (most recent call last):
```

I have changed the credentials multiple times, all to no avail.

Also, I get this error in the awslogs.log file:

```
2017-06-12 16:31:40,862 - cwlogs.push.reader -
WARNING - 31909 - Thread-8 - Fall back to previous event time: 
{'timestamp': 1497246644000, 'start_position': 7142L, 'end_position': 
7246L}, previousEventTime: 1497246644000, reason: timestamp could not 
be parsed from message.
```

I am using the following format:

```
[/var/log/tomcat8/catalina.out]
datetime_format = %d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S
file = /var/log/tomcat8/catalina.out
buffer_duration = 5000
log_stream_name = {instance_id}
initial_position = start_of_file
log_group_name = Catalina
```

Any help at this point will be appreciated.

Comment: How are you supplying credentials to the CloudWatch logs agent (awslogs)? Ideally, your instance would have an IAM role associated with it and that IAM role would have a policy that allows the various logging actions (see policy document at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/QuickStartEC2Instance.html).

Comment: Hi, I fixed it. Thanks to @saopayne.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly append "sudo" to the "aws configure" command.